# Apache Derby sample database issue; 'Unable to connect'

Tags: java, derby

I am running Netbeans 8.02 on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit, and the other day I discovered that I can't access the 'sample' Derby database any longer. I get the following error:

> Unable to connect. Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample using
>   org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver (DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE: 40000, SQLSTATE:XJ040, SQLERRMC:
>   Failed to start database 'sample' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@60e53b93, see
>   the next exception for details.::SQLSTATE:XSLAM).

Apache Derby is running and it otherwise seems in good working order. The only things using the 'sample' database are the apps from this completed tutorial: [Enterprise application tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/javafx_json_tutorial/javafx_javaee7_json_tutorial.html)

That's the only thing that I can think of that might have caused this error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It says `see the next exception for details` but we can't because it is not posted. Can you post the full exception with stack trace?

Comment: You should have some "Cannot verify database format at <directoryPath> due to IOException: <exceptionDetails>" message according to the [doc](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/ref/rrefexcept71493.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for replying. Here's what I found in the logs:

```
        Sat Jan 23 13:30:29 GMT 2016:
    Booting Derby version The Apache Software Foundation 
    - Apache Derby - 10.11.1.2 - (1629631): instancE f67740d7-0152-6ead-        1de3-00003d273097 

    on database directory C:\Users\user\.netbeans-derby\sample with class loader 
    sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@60e53b93 
    Loaded from file:
    /C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_40/db/lib/derby.jar
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    java.runtime.version=1.8.0_40-b25
    user.
    dir=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\db
    os.name=Windows 8.1
    os.arch=amd64
    os.version=6.3
    derby.system.home=C:\Users\user\.netbeans-derby

    ------------  Begin Shutdown Error Stack -------------

    ERROR XSLA7: Cannot redo operation null in the log.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.FileLogger.redo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.recover(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.RawStore.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootStore(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.Database.makeConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.getConnFromDatabaseName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.verifyUserIdPassword(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.parseSECCHK(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.parseDRDAConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.processCommands(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: ERROR XSLAM: Cannot verify database format at {1} due to IOException: C:\Users\user\.netbeans-derby\sample
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.verifyLogFormat(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.getLogFileAtPosition(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.getLogFileAtBeginning(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.Scan.getNextRecordForward(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.Scan.getNextRecord(Unknown Source)
    ... 36 more
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readInt(RandomAccessFile.java:803)
    ... 41 more
    ============= begin nested exception, level (1) ===========
    ERROR XSLAM: Cannot verify database format at {1} due to IOException: C:\Users\user\.netbeans-derby\sample
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.verifyLogFormat(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.getLogFileAtPosition(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.getLogFileAtBeginning(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.Scan.getNextRecordForward(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.Scan.getNextRecord(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.FileLogger.redo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.recover(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.RawStore.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootStore(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.Database.makeConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.getConnFromDatabaseName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.verifyUserIdPassword(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.parseSECCHK(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.parseDRDAConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.processCommands(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readInt(RandomAccessFile.java:803)
        ... 41 more
    ============= end nested exception, level (1) ===========
    ============= begin nested exception, level (2) ===========
    java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readInt(RandomAccessFile.java:803)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.verifyLogFormat(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.getLogFileAtPosition(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.getLogFileAtBeginning(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.Scan.getNextRecordForward(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.Scan.getNextRecord(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.FileLogger.redo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.recover(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.RawStore.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootStore(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.Database.makeConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.getConnFromDatabaseName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.verifyUserIdPassword(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.parseSECCHK(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.parseDRDAConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.processCommands(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.run(Unknown Source)
    ============= end nested exception, level (2) ===========
    ------------  End Shutdown Error Stack -------------

    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    Sat Jan 23 13:30:29 GMT 2016:
    Shutting down instance f67740d7-0152-6ead-1de3-00003d273097 on database directory C:\Users\user\.netbeans-derby\sample with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@60e53b93 
    Sat Jan 23 13:30:29 GMT 2016 Thread[DRDAConnThread_3,5,main] Cleanup action starting
        java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'sample' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@60e53b93, see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.Database.makeConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.getConnFromDatabaseName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.verifyUserIdPassword(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.parseSECCHK(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.parseDRDAConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.processCommands(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: ERROR XJ040: Failed to start database 'sample' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@60e53b93, see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more
    Caused by: ERROR XSLAM: Cannot verify database format at {1} due to IOException: C:\Users\user\.netbeans-derby\sample
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.verifyLogFormat(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.getLogFileAtPosition(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.getLogFileAtBeginning(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.Scan.getNextRecordForward(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.Scan.getNextRecord(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.FileLogger.redo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.recover(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.RawStore.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootStore(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readInt(RandomAccessFile.java:803)
    ... 41 more
    ============= begin nested exception, level (1) ===========
    java.sql.SQLException: Cannot verify database format at {1} due to IOException: 
    C:\Users\user\.netbeans-derby\sample
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.Database.makeConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.getConnFromDatabaseName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.verifyUserIdPassword(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.parseSECCHK(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.parseDRDAConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.processCommands(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: ERROR XSLAM: Cannot verify database format at {1} due to IOException: 
    C:\Users\user\.netbeans-derby\sample
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.verifyLogFormat(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.getLogFileAtPosition(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.getLogFileAtBeginning(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.Scan.getNextRecordForward(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.Scan.getNextRecord(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.FileLogger.redo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.log.LogToFile.recover(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.RawStore.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootStore(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readInt(RandomAccessFile.java:803)
    ... 41 more
    ============= end nested exception, level (1) ===========
```

Comment: Ouch. It looks like the Derby transaction log was damaged. Did you fill up your C:\ disk? Did you have a power failure, or a crash of some sort? Did you make a backup of the database?

Comment: I had some Windows related problems, but no crashes while connected to the sample database thankfully. I have a 1Tb C:\ drive and plenty of surplus space. I hadn't backed up the database sadly, so thats why I am hoping for a solution here.

Comment: I found a solution by deleting and recreating the sample database from this create script: http://code.metager.de/source/xref/netbeans/derby/etc/sample.sql

Comment: Nice one Chalmers, thanks for following up with the solution :)

Comment: Interestingly a near identical scenario arose when I completed the Enterprise application tutorial for the second time recently. The web application caused an error in the Derby sample database - the same unable to connect error. The simple solution was to stop and start Derby and a connection could then be established. I'd be interested in feedback from other users who have completed the tutorial. Here is the link: [link](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/javafx_json_tutorial/javafx_javaee7_json_tutorial.html#overview)